# What are MapFish Printing Capabilities for WMS and WFS?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, wfs, printing, mapfish

we are evaluating whether MapFish Printing module fit our needs or not.. From a 2010 presentation http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations/3234.pdf, it says MapFish printing has following readers:

- Web Map Server (WMS)
- Google Maps
- Tile Map Server (TMS)
- Image
- KaMap
- KaMapCache
- Open Street Map (OSM)
- Tile Cache
- GeoJSON

I am wondering does it support

- ArcGIS Server WMS?
- OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGISCache layer?

besides, what about **WFS**? 
It lists GeoJSON, does this mean it supports ***GeoJSON-Based WFS***?
again, **ArcGIS Server WFS**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, ArcGIS Server WMS works with MapFish Print
2. No, you cannot use ArcGISCache
3. No, I grep'ed the mapfish readers and found no WFS references
4. Specifically, there is no WFS in VectorMapReader.java

Answer (score 1):

MapFish will not support WFS as in it is not possible to send a WFS URL in the same way that you can with a WMS. However, it is possible to send the contents of a WFS request to MapFish and this is where the GeoJSON format comes in.

When you send a request to MapFish for printing you send details of the layers to be included on the map. In most cases this will be parameters for a WMS, Google, or OpenStreetMap layer or combination thereof. It is also possible to send vector features along with styling information (based on OpenLayers syntax I believe) as the properties for a layer. So, if your client application allows it you could encode the contents of your WFS based vector layer as GeoJSON and send it as part of the print request.

I use OpenLayers and have taken this approach to allow printing of the vector layers in the map along with WMS layers.